# Deleting entries in Phone book

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I was asked to make a Phone Book thats saves entries and call them up. Then the teacher added a new task. The Program should delete entries. He gave us a methode and said we are not allowed to use ArrayList or Hashmaps, ONLY Arrays. I tried alot but just could not seem to get it right, Can someone please help correcting my mistakes?
There are 2 Classes: `PhoneBook` and `UI`

```
    import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
public class PhoneBook {
    private static int maxSize = 100; 
    private static int actSize = 0; 
    private static String[] name = new String[maxSize]; 
    private static String[] firstName = new String[maxSize]; 
    private static String[] number = new String[maxSize]; 
    public static String findEntry(String nameP, String firstNameP) {
        for (int i = 0; i < actSize; i++) {
            if (name[i].equals(nameP) && firstName[i].equals(firstNameP)) {
                return number[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static void addEntry(String nameP, String firstNameP, String numberP) {
        if (actSize == maxSize) {
            System.err.println("Memory full!");
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < actSize; i++) {
            if (name[i].equals(nameP) && firstName[i].equals(firstNameP)) {
                System.err.println("It exists already!");
                return;
            }
        }
        name[actSize] = nameP;
        firstName[actSize] = firstNameP;
        number[actSize] = numberP;
        actSize = actSize + 1;
    }
    public static String getActionDialog(String... actions) { 
        JRadioButton[] buttons = new JRadioButton[actions.length];
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        for (int i = 0; i<actions.length; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JRadioButton(actions[i]);
            group.add(buttons[i]);
        }
    buttons[0].setSelected(true);
    Object[] message = buttons;
    Object[] options = { "OK", "Cancel"};
    int n= JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
            message,
            "Choose an Action",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null,
            options,
            options[0]);
    if(n==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
        for (int i = 0; i<actions.length; i++) {
            if(buttons[i].isSelected()){
                return actions[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
    }
    /**
     * Deletes Entries.
     * An entry matches the pattern if it fits in all components (name, first name, number).
     * A component fits, when it is equal to the sample component, or the component pattern of the empty string.
     * 
     * @param nameP         Pattern for the name of the entries to be deleted.
     * @param firstNameP    Pattern for the first names of the entries to be deleted.
     * @param numberP       Pattern for the number of entries to be deleted.
     * @post  all matching entries are deleted. The capacity remains unchanged.
     *        The size is adjusted.
     * @return Number of deleted entries.
     */
    public static int deleteMatchingEntries(String nameP, String firstNameP,
        String numberP) {
    for (int i = 0; i < actSize; i++) {
        if (name[i].equals(nameP)) {
            name[i] = name[i + 1];

            actSize--;
        } else if (firstName[i].equals(firstNameP)) {
            firstName[i] = firstName[i + 1];

            actSize--;
        } else if (number[i].equals(numberP)) {
            number[i] = number[i + 1];

            actSize--;
        }
    }
    return actSize;
}
}



import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class UI {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            String action = PhoneBook.getActionDialog(
                    "Create an entry", "Call up an entry","Delete Entry");
            if (action == null) {
                break;
            }
            if (action.equals("Create an entry")) {
                String[] entryData = getEntryDataDialog();
                if (entryData != null) {
                    PhoneBook.addEntry(entryData[0], entryData[1],
                            entryData[2]);
                }
            } else if (action.equals("Call up an entry")) {
                String[] queryData = getQueryDataDialog();
                if (queryData != null) {
                    String nr = PhoneBook.findEntry(queryData[0],
                            queryData[1]);
                    if (nr == null) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not found");
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Last Name: "
                                + queryData[0] + ", First Name: " + queryData[1]
                                + ", Number:" + nr);
                    }
                }else if (action.equals("Delete Entry")) {
            String[] delete = getEntryDataDialog();
            if (delete != null) {
                TelephoneDirectory.deleteMatchingEntries(delete[0],
                        delete[1], delete[2]);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entry deleted");

            }
        } else {
                System.err.println("Error: unknow Action " + action);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private static String[] getEntryDataDialog() {
        JTextField nameTF = new JTextField();
        JTextField firstNameTF = new JTextField();
        JTextField numberTF = new JTextField();
        Object[] message = { "Last Name", nameTF, "First Name", firstNameTF, "Number",
                numberTF };
        Object[] options = { "OK", "Cancel" };
        int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, message, "Create an entry",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
                options, options[0]);
        if (n == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) { 
            return new String[] { nameTF.getText(), firstNameTF.getText(),
                    numberTF.getText() };
        } else if (n == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION
                || n == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) { 
            return null;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    private static String[] getQueryDataDialog() {
        JTextField nameTF = new JTextField();
        JTextField firstNameTF = new JTextField();
        Object[] message = { "Last Name", nameTF, "First Name", firstNameTF };
        Object[] options = { "OK", "Cancel" };
        int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, message, "Call up an entry",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
                options, options[0]);
        if (n == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) { 
            return new String[] { nameTF.getText(), firstNameTF.getText() };
        } else if (n == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION 
                || n == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) { 
            return null;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you seeing?  What have you tried?

Comment: please ask a more specific question. what are your errors?

Comment: You should post the specific problems that it's giving you rather than leaving people to read all of the code to figure out what's might be going wrong.

Comment: [crossposted](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/469627/deleting-entries-in-phonebook)

Comment: sorry, if I save some entries and try to delete one of them, lets say i want to delete the 3rd entry, if I delete the Last Name of the 3rd, the Last Name of the 4th entry will take place of the deleted Last Name and the 5th entry will be deleted completely and the First Name and Number of the 3rd entry will not change.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you are moving only one record up when you delete an entry.

Here are some changes that you could do:

1 - (If allowed by the teacher) Create a PhoneEntry class that will hold one name, lastName and number

2 - (Again if allowed) Change your 3 arrays to be just one array of PhoneEntry objects (it makes it easier to handle)

3 - When doing a deletion you don't need to move the next entry up, you just put null on the place where you deleted the PhoneEntry. Also you will change the meaning of actSize to actQuantity and for the next entry addition you will search for the first position in the array that has a null value.

Cheers

Comment: Gonna agree here, realllly doesn't make sense to use 3 separate arrays if you don't have to.

Comment: unfortunately, it is not allowed.

Comment: @user3054620 although not allowed to use a single class the recommendation number 3 will correct your deletion problem, but you will have to do it in the 3 arrays.

Comment: I got it!
Thanks alot for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a single array of e.g. Class Contact or something.

If you look at:

```
public static int deleteMatchingEntries(String nameP, String firstNameP,
        String numberP) {
    for (int i = 0; i < actSize; i++) {
        if (name[i].equals(nameP)) {
            name[i] = name[i + 1];

            actSize--;
        } else if (firstName[i].equals(firstNameP)) {
            firstName[i] = firstName[i + 1];

            actSize--;
        } else if (number[i].equals(numberP)) {
            number[i] = number[i + 1];

            actSize--;
        }
    }
    return actSize;
}
```

Say you have something like this "Doe, John, 555-5555" all at the [0] position in your array. Your function will Delete Doe, then keep John and 555. Suddenly your indexes don't match up.

Furthermore, I would take the deleteMatchingEntries and refactor out the array deletion logic to a separate function that you can test separately.